# How to replace a Hugo theme's default homepage and define a custom route?

Tags: static, frontend, hugo, jamstack

I have been building a personal portfolio site and blog using the **Hugo** theme [LoveIt](https://themes.gohugo.io/themes/loveit/). As the theme is heavily blog-centric, I want to replace the theme's homepage with my custom static HTML page and keep the theme's default homepage available at the `/blog` URL.

For example,
If the site's URL is `example.com`.
I want to have my `custom.html` page available at `example.com` and the theme's default homepage at `example.com/blog`.

I have searched Hugo docs and forums but didn't find any official document or best practice for changing routes or homepage. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Resource you were looking for that covers how to edit/change homepage](https://gohugo.io/templates/homepage/#readout)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to place your `custom.html` content as `index.html` in the `layouts/` directory located off the root of your site as `layouts/index.html`.

This should override the theme's index.html page.

Comment: Thanks @m2web. I did replace the default homepage by overriding `index.html`. But, I mentioned this in the question _"....the theme's default homepage at example.com/blog."_ Can you help me in this regard?

Comment: I understood that you had your updated `index.html` in `example.com/blog` folder as `example.com/blog/index.html`. It should be in the `example.com/layouts` folder as `example.com/layouts/index.html`.

Comment: Hi @Blackernel, did you find a way to do this ? I am facing the same issue and do not find a solution. Thanks